# Upload an audio file to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: facebook, audio, twitter, upload

Is it possible to upload an audio file to Facebook and Twitter?

I tried a lot and do googling but no success so far. So I just want to confirm:

1. Facebook API for upload audio file
2. Twitter API for upload audio file

What is the API link if it is supported?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Twitter only supports text and Facebook only supports text, images, and video. You could consider using something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the files and post links to Twitter/Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add audio to twitter, then you can use services like http://tvider.com/

Another method is, start your own Audio uploading and sharing website, and you can tweet the link from your website through Twitter API.

Example:

`Hoorey!! This is my first audio tweet!!! http://aud.it/3yU2d`

`(2 minutes ago via Aud.it)`

Where I just named it as "Aud.it" or http://aud.it/ thats all!

**Some mathematics:**

This audio tweets can be of a fixed length, say 15 seconds, and a constant bitrate of 8kbps (enough for speech voice recording).

So, total (8Kbps/8bits)*15s = 15KB for each recording.

In 1MB, you can have nearly 540 records, and in 1 GB, 70,000 recordings.

Also for delivering a single audio tweet, you need less than 1 second on a normal 40Kbps dial-up line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend simply making an mp4 file without video, this is probably the closest you will get, and it has official support.